# Fixar nome em campo de busca

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Neste [html](http://parciais.competicaocartolafc.com/parciais_cartolafc/Parciais_Box_1.htm) existe o campo de busca, onde digito o nome dos times.

Existe a opção de salvar o time como padrão, porém gostaria de deixar o nome já salvo, toda vez que abrir a pagina ele já abra buscando o time automático...

O Arquivo esta em meu desktop, assim a ideia era deixar várias copias de vários times aqui comigo, para fazerem os testes segue alguns times que podem ser lançados nesse campo: **Ice Blood**, **Renascitur**, **JPHS** e **Fitnns**.

Comment: Você precisará salvar o nome do time quando é seleciona como salvar como time padrão, aí depois jogará esse campo no value citado no comentário acima.

Comment: Testei todas as dicas e nenhuma funcionou.

Comment: Se alguma resposta te ajudou ou resolveu seu problema, dê um voto e marque como a resposta correta, caso contrário, informe mais detalhes sobre o que tentou e os resultados que obteve. Sempre votar e escolher as respostas corretas é uma boa prática e ajuda os outros usuários.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

não consegui ver o seu exemplo, mas você pode usar IndexedDB.
para tal você pode armazenar o seu filtro no IndexedDB com o seguinte formato:

```
{
    id: "<inteiro auto-incremental>"
    timeA: "<nome do time A>",
    timeB: "<nome do time B>",
    selected: true/false
}
```

para criar o banco no IndexedDB, faça o seguinte:

```
var dbName = "filtros";
var db = null;
var request = indexedDB.open(dbName);

request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
  var db = event.target.result;
  var objectStore = db.createObjectStore(dbName, { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
  objectStore.createIndex("times", ["timeA", "timeB"], { unique: true });
  objectStore.createIndex("selected", "selected", { unique: false });
};

request.onsuccess = function(event) {
  db = request.result;
}
```

segue um exemplo das operações basicas com o IndexedDB:

**Pegar todos os Registros:**

```
var objectStore = db.transaction(dbName).objectStore(dbName);
objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;   
    if (cursor) {
        var id = cursor.key;
        var filtro = cursor.value
        cursor.continue();
    }
 };
```

**Pegar Registro pelo ID:**

```
var objectStore = db.transaction(dbName).objectStore(dbName);
var request = objectStore.get(id)
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var filtro= request.result;
};
```

**Inserir Registro:**

```
var objectStore = db.transaction(dbName).objectStore(dbName);
var request = objectStore.add(filtro)
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    filtro.id = event.target.result;
};
```

**Atualizar Registro:**

```
var objectStore = db.transaction(dbName).objectStore(dbName);
var request = objectStore.put(filtro)
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    //registro atualizado.
};
```

Uma vez feito isto, você terá total controle sobre os registros salvos.
Segue um exemplo completo:

```js
var filtros = document.getElementById("filtros");
var filtro = document.getElementById("filtro");
var timeA = document.getElementById("timeA");
var timeB = document.getElementById("timeB");
var salvar = document.getElementById("salvar");
var selected = null;

var dbName = "filtros";
var db = null;
var request = indexedDB.open(dbName);

request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
  var db = event.target.result;
  var objectStore = db.createObjectStore(dbName, { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
  objectStore.createIndex("times", ["timeA", "timeB"], { unique: true });
  objectStore.createIndex("selected", "selected", { unique: false });
};

request.onsuccess = function(event) {
  db = request.result;
  var objectStore = db.transaction(dbName).objectStore(dbName);
  objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
    var cursor = event.target.result;   
    if (cursor) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = cursor.key;
      option.textContent = cursor.value.timeA + " x " + cursor.value.timeB;
      filtros.appendChild(option);
      if (cursor.value.selected) {      
        selected = cursor.value;
        filtros.selectedIndex = filtros.options.length - 1;
        filtro.disabled = "disabled";
        timeA.value = selected.timeA;
        timeB.value = selected.timeB;
      }
      cursor.continue();
    }
  };
};

var atualizarFiltro = function () {
  var newSelected = parseInt(filtros.options[filtros.selectedIndex].value);
  filtro.disabled = newSelected != 0;  
  
  if (newSelected != 0) {
    var objectStore = db.transaction([dbName], "readwrite").objectStore(dbName);
    var request = objectStore.get(newSelected)
    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
      var selected = request.result;
      timeA.value = selected.timeA;
      timeB.value = selected.timeB;
      selected.selected = true;
      objectStore.put(selected);
    };
  } else {
    timeA.value = "";
    timeB.value = "";
  }
}


filtros.addEventListener("change", function () {
  if (selected) {
    var objectStore = db.transaction([dbName], "readwrite").objectStore(dbName);
    selected.selected = false;
    var request = objectStore.put(selected);
    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
      atualizarFiltro();
    };
  } else {
    atualizarFiltro();
  }
});

salvar.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (timeA.value && timeB.value && timeA.value != timeB.value) {
    var registro = { timeA: timeA.value, timeB: timeB.value, selected: true };
    var objectStore = db.transaction([dbName], "readwrite").objectStore(dbName);
    var request = objectStore.add(registro);
    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
     registro.id = event.target.result;
     var selected = registro;
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = selected.id;
      option.textContent = registro.timeA + " x " + registro.timeB;
      filtros.appendChild(option);
      filtros.selectedIndex = filtros.options.length - 1;
      filtro.disabled = "disabled";
    };
    request.onerror  = function(event) {
      alert(event.srcElement.error.message);
    };
  } 
});
```

```css
.linha {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

fieldset {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px none transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="linha">
  <label for="filtros">Filtros:</label>
  <select id="filtros">
    <option value="0">Novo Filtro</option>
  </select>  
</div>
<div class="linha">
  <fieldset id="filtro">
  <label>
    Time A:
    <input id="timeA" type="text" list="times" />
  </label>
  x
  <label>
    Time B:
    <input id="timeB" type="text" list="times" />
  </label>
  <input id="salvar" type="button" value="Salvar" />
  </fieldset>
</div>
<datalist id="times">
  <option>Ice Blood</option>
  <option>Renascitur</option>
  <option>JPHS</option>
  <option>Fitnns</option>
</datalist>
```

O Exemplo acima não funciona, devido à uma limitação do Snippet do StackOverFlow, mas você pode conferir o mesmo no [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/TobyMosque/m6k0ytrL/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Não estou conseguindo abrir a página aqui onde trabalho, mas se a tag é neste modelo:

```
<input type="text" name="algumName" value="COLOQUE AQUI O NOME DO TIME PADRAO"/>
```

Fazendo isso, inicialmente o textbox viria com o que você escrevesse no atributo value escrito

Coloque trechos do seu código pois isso varia muito de como você se comunica com seu servidor, mas basicamente o que está setado no campo value é o que está escrito, se quiser dar um submit de algum form de consulta após a página estar carregada você pode usar o query para isso;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#IdBotaoSubmitSeuForm").click(); 
 //ou voce pode usar     
 $('#idDoSeuForm').submit();


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu trabalharia com cookies utilizando o plugin [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

No momento que o usuário seleciona a opção `Salvar como time padrão` você pega o valor do campo e salva no cookie dessa forma:

```
$.cookie("time_a_padrao", "Renascitur");
$.cookie("time_b_padrao", "JPHS");
```

Quando a página carregar, você pode usar o próprio jQuery `$(document).load()` e ver se existem cookies com os nomes `time_a_padrao` e `time_b_padrao` e pegar os valores dessa forma:

```
$.cookie("time_a_padrao");
```

Coloque o valor desse cookie no seu input e faz a pesquisa.

Para você excluir um cookie, caso o usuário deseja que o time padrão seja outro, faça dessa forma:

```
$.removeCookie("time_a_padrao");
```